# How to refactor a huge react component with a lot of handlers?

Tags: reactjs

So we have a 500 line component which manages a huge view with a lot of handlers and useEffects.

I already moved all the states to a context since the component has like 10 child components which had a lot of prop drilling.

But the main component still has a lot of handlers and useEffects which make 90% of the component code.

I though about making utils but each handler/useEffect use like 5-8 variables so I'd have to pass a lot of parameters to the utils and I think it'll make the code less readable.

Any solution for this case?

Comment: try converting `useEffects` into `custom hooks` which reduces lot of code in main component.. and try `useReducer` if you have lot of states(`useState`) and they are updating all at once.. there are lot of good quality youtube videos which explains how and why to use `custom hooks` and `useReducer`

Comment: Also, Don't maintain states with Context bcuz Context has lot of caveats and may affect your app's performance by doing unnecessary re-renders.. Try Redux.. Redux is verbose but serves the purpose.. Im using Context in my org app and it sucks.. now we are the point of no return.. if you are the initial phase, conside going with any state management tools instead of context